# Observable/Subscriber in AsyncTask

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I'm trying to implement an Observable/Subscriber with `RxJava` on the `onPostExecute()` of an `AsyncTask` and I don't get how to make the connection.
I create the `Observable` in the `onPostExecute` method. I want `MyFragment` to subscribe to this. How do I set this up?

```
public class LoadAndStoreDataTask extends AsyncTask<String,  Integer,  String> {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // create the observable    
        Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.create(
                new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                        subscriber.onNext(result);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                }
        );

        myObservable.subscribe(mySubscriber);
    }
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Subscriber<String> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) { System.out.println(s); }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() { }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) { }
        };
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `RxJava` and `AsyncTask`s are solving the same kind of problems. There is no any reason to use both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually RxJava is supposed to replace AsycTask. In fact I can say with confidence that AsyncTask is a subset of RxJava.

In RxJava, a Subscriber would be analogous to `AsyncTask.progressUpdate` or `onPostExecute` and Observable to the process in `doInBackground`. Data are emitted from Observable to Subscriber and any alteration in this stream is done with mapping methods. You probably don't need mapping now so I would reconfigure my RxJava like this:

```
 Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.create(
        new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {                      
               try{
                   String res = ...//your original doInBackground                       
                   subscriber.onNext(res); 
                   // onNext would be comparable to AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate 
                   // and usually applies when backgorund process runs a loop
                   subscriber.onCompleted();
               }catch (SomeException e){
                   // if the process throws an exception or produces a result 
                   // you'd consider error then use onError                         
                   subscriber.onError(e);
               }
            }
        }
 )
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // If subscriber runs on UI thread
 .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onNext(String response) {
          // result from Observable.onNext. The methods below correspond
          // to their Observable counterparts. 
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {}

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {}
 });
```

`AndroidSchedulers` is available in RxAndroid. To use it add this line to build.gradle :

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting there. 2 questions: 1. Where do I put the code defining `mySubscriber`? The subscriber is `MyFragment` 2. Android studio has no idea what `AndroidSchedulers`, i.e. doesn't give the option to Alt-Enter the import. How do I access this?

Comment: I should add that I have the code you posted in MainActivity.OnCreate()

Comment: It is available in RxAndroid which is used along RxJava. To answer the first, well RxJava is about Observer-Subscriber pattern. The whole process starts only when a Subscriber is attached to an Observable (e.g with `subscribe` above). So you can pass an Observable instance and attach your Subscriber implementation in some click listener or one of the lifecycle methods. What do you use your Observable for anyway ?

Comment: A RESTful service is being observed. When the data is received from it and stored into the SQlite db on the device then I want to notify the Fragment that is subscribed that the data is ready to use.

Comment: Right so it doesn't matter where you put your Observable. You might as well chain them both together wherever in the Fragment that triggers the process. Personally however, I'd do long running task in the Activity and then broadcast the result with event bus. This way at the end of subscription, I'd avoid updating views of fragment that has been destroyed.

Comment: *I'd do long running task in the Activity and then broadcast the result with event bus*. Do you mean not to use RxJava, but rather something  like GreenRobot's event bus?

Comment: Or Otto or RxBus. "Event bus" is originally a concept. The point is you can use both. You can use event bus to broadcast result from `Subcsriber.onNext` or `onComplete` for example. Unlike Activity, Fragment is very fragile. The danger is when you explicitly do something like `textView.setText` in these methods because the said view may not be around when onDestroyView has been called. With event bus, you may define a subscriber strategy in which broadcast result gets digested only between `Fragment.onCreateView` and `onDestroyView` or when the views are still alive.